# Error in converting the json value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I am trying to get the value from the serverside but i can't get it..Here, i am trying to convert the json data using JSON.parse(); but it is not working in jQuery... i don't know how to solve this...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
            $.ajax({    
                url:'http://newslet.comxa.com/NewsRecord.php' ,
                    dataType:'json',
                success:function(output_string) {
                    temp=JSON.parse(output_string);
                for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
                {
                     $('#level').append('<div>Title &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:'+temp[i].Title+'<br>Source  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<a href='+temp[i].links+'>'+temp[i].Source+'</a><br>Category :'+temp[i].Category+'</div><hr>');
                 }                      
                }
             });
        });
```

i get this output when i am running these path 'http://newslet.comxa.com/NewsRecord.php'..

```
[{"Id":"2","Date":"","Title":"Hitachi Data Systems bets big on analytics","Source":"TOI","Category":"Corporate","links":"http:\/\/timesofindia.indiatimes.com\/tech\/tech-news\/software-services\/Hitachi-Data-Systems-bets-big-on-analytics\/articleshow\/26542988.cms?"},{"Id":"3","Date":"","Title":"British bike company Triumph drives into India","Source":"TOI","Category":"Industry","links":"http:\/\/timesofindia.indiatimes.com\/business\/india-business\/British-bike-company-Triumph-drives-into-India\/articleshow\/26542881.cms"}]
```

Comment: where have u declared var temp?

Comment: is there any error caught up in console?

Comment: try using this function $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(id, row) {})

Comment: if i run using this $.each($.parseJSOn(data),fun) function i get this output in console....[10:51:18.859] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string already is a valid json so there isnt any need to use

```
JSON.parse(output_string);
```

Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/uDr6t/

Comment: i tried what u said but in that i got this console error...[11:10:26.222] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2

Comment: can u create fiddle for same

Comment: have u seen my fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

you need to stringify first json result.

```
var json = JSON.stringify([{"Id":"2","Date":"","Title":"Hitachi Data Systems bets big on analytics","Source":"TOI","Category":"Corporate","links":"http:\/\/timesofindia.indiatimes.com\/tech\/tech-news\/software-services\/Hitachi-Data-Systems-bets-big-on-analytics\/articleshow\/26542988.cms?"},{"Id":"3","Date":"","Title":"British bike company Triumph drives into India","Source":"TOI","Category":"Industry","links":"http:\/\/timesofindia.indiatimes.com\/business\/india-business\/British-bike-company-Triumph-drives-into-India\/articleshow\/26542881.cms"}]);

var temp = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: I think he doesnt even need to do this can loop through output_string only